# How do I compile a debug build of GCC?

Tags: gcc

I followed the steps on the page:
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebuggingGCC#gccbuilddebug

Exact commands I did:

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --enable-stage1-languages=c --disable-multilib
make STAGE1_CXXFLAGS="-g -O0" all-stage1
```

I only get various xgcc or cc1 executables.

Command I need from gcc:

`gcc -S test.c` results in:

`"xgcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory"`

I need the gcc binary because I need to debug the `-S` switch and otherwise I get this error if I just use cc1: `cc1: error: command line option ‘-S’ is valid for the driver but not for C`

Answer (score 1):

GCC driver (`xgcc`) expects compiler proper (`cc1`) to be in a standard location but standard directory layout is only created during installation (`make install`). To run newly built but not yet installed GCC, use the infamous `-B` flag:

```
GCC_BUILD=path/to/build/dir
$GCC_BUILD/xgcc -B$GCC_BUILD -S test.c
```

(BTW that's how `make check` invokes GCC when running GCC testsuite).